# Wordpress custom post parent slug

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

What is the best way to structure a parent/child custom post type combo, so that my slug url can look like this

`https://www.mysite.co.uk/system/parent/child`

The **system** part of the slug is vital, it is part of the multiple theme plugin for wordpress. Also, the parent/child parts of the url will not always be the same. Lets say I make a course called "How to ride a bike", and a series inside it called "Series 1", my slug needs to look like this

`https://www.mysite.co.uk/system/how-to-ride-a-bike/series-1`

at the moment my custom post types look like this

```
<?php
function create_post_type() {
    //Courses
    register_post_type( 'courses',
      [
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => __( 'Courses' ),
          'singular_name' => __( 'Course' )
        ),
        'description' => 'All courses',
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'       => 'system',
        ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        'supports' => ['title', 'custom_fields', 'page-attributes']
      ]
    );

    //Series
    register_post_type( 'series',
        [
          'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Series' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Series' )
          ),
          'show_ui'              => true,
          'show_in_menu'         => 'edit.php?post_type=courses',
          'description' => 'Course series',
          'public' => true,
          'rewrite'             => array('slug' => '/'),
          'hierarchical'        => true,
          'with_front'          => false,
          'capability_type'     => 'post',
          'has_archive'         => false,
          'supports' => ['title', 'custom_fields', 'page-attributes']
        ]
      );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
?>
```

I'm not 100% sure on the best way to actually link the child element to the parent? At the moment I have an advanced custom field on the child post type (series) where you select the parent (course) its linked to.

What is the best way to structure my custom post types, so that I can link a child to a parent and have the slug specified above?

Comment: WordPress doesn't support one post type being a child of another post type.  Do they both need to be post types? Is "System" really just a "container" for Series?  Normally you'd EITHER have them all be the same post type, and / or you'd manage this sort of thing with taxonomies.  If the URL rewrite is your main goal and the post types are your attempt to get there, then I'd recommend either using taxonomies (a custom "hierarchical"  taxonomy) or else tapping into the [Rewrite API](https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/)

Comment: If I did them both as the same post type, is there a way I can have 'courses' in the menu, then when you create a course and click it, it gives me the option to make a list of series (same list style as posts/pages)?

Comment: @S_R may e you can make a hierarchical taxonomy instead of post similar to category and subcategory.

Comment: If you made them all the same post type, you could have "parent" posts list their "children" posts, yes.  So a parent "course" could then list out the child "classes", yes.  And I would encourage you to use a custom taxnoomy (heirarchical) in order to achieve the url structure you are after ("categories" are a heirarchical taxonomy, where one category can be a child of another category -  "tags" are not, there's no parent / child relationships with tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent/child structures of the same custom post type using the `page-attributes` value in the `supports` array.

You do need to flush the rewrite rules of Wordpress before adding the sub-item. Just visit the permalinks page and hit save a couple of times.

Here is my example with the custom post type `subcase`:

```
register_post_type( 'subcase',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true, // needs to be true
        'labels'      => array(
            'name'          => __( 'Sub Cases' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Sub Case' )
        ),
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'public'      => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'rewrite'     => array(
            'slug'       => 'cases/subcases',
            'with_front' => true
        ),
        'supports'    => array(
            'page-attributes', // creates parent select box
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail'
        )
    )
);
```